# Does a WCF Service that runs over tcp.net require IIS

Tags: iis, wcf, nettcpbinding

I'm trying to deploy a WCF service that uses a netTcpBinding (and a mexTcpBinding for metadata) on a remote server (Win 2008 R2) without installing IIS.

Trouble is, everything I'm trying is telling me I need various IIS components installed on the remote box.
Is that really the case? It seems to me that, with a tcp.net connection, I should be fine without IIS.

Comment: Which IIS components are you being told to use, and what is telling you to use them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need IIS, here's an MSDN article called How to: [Host WCF in a Windows Service Using TCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx)

It seems to be fairly detailed and easy to follow.

Comment: Excellent! That looks like it will cover all I need. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 6):

In general, it is not necessary to use IIS for a WCF service. Any WCF service can be self-hosted.

Answer (score 2):

A WCF service needs to be hosted somewhere. If you don't want to use IIS you need to write a [host application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb332338%28v=msdn.10%29) which could be console or a Windows NT service application. If you choose to host your service in IIS, starting from IIS 7 you could use [non HTTP bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/swiss_dpe_team/iis-7-support-for-non-http-protocols).